# Android Virtual Device - Windows 7 BSOD

Tags: android, cordova

I have just started playing around with Android development and looking to use PhoneGap.

Using their getting started guide (http://phonegap.com/start#android) I have got to the final step, which is running the app in an Android Virtual Device.

I have set some up and all of which cause a BSOD when ever I try to run it. I am using Windows 7.

The error message displayed on the BSOD is:

```
STOP: 0X0000008E

emBDA.sys - Address 8EB5320C base at 8EB50000
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with file emBDA64.sys. Probably it is the same problem that I had, but you have 32-bit driver not 64-bit. This file is part of probably PVR-TV USB device. I had to turn off this device and emulator started to work well. Check, what device is this file a part of and turn off this device when using emulator. Probably it is extrnal TV tuner too.

Answer (score 1):

**Confirming kzez1986's suggestion** that the BSOD might have to do, or always has to do (?) with a(n internal) **USB TV tuner**.
My Win7-64 system suffered from the same BSOD after a brand new install of the Android SDK and starting a new AVD.

When **disabling a USB device**, in my case called '**DVBT Hybrid TV Device**' in the 'Sound, video and game controllers' section of the windows Device Manager I could now start the Android AVD without problems.
Note: Because I'm on a 64bit machine, in my case the BSOD error was pointing to emBDA64.sys.